# Java web start app reporting GMT time zone

Tags: java

I have a java application using java web start 1.4.2_13 running on windows 2008 server. The application functions but it report time in GMT. Server is set to EST time zone. 
How can I force the application to use EST. ?
Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timezone like this:

```
System.setProperty("user.timezone", "EST");
```

Please note that this code has to be called in the beginning before calling any date function. Otherwise it will not take affect.

Or you could pass the parameter `-Duser.timezone="EST"` to the JVM.

Comment: hi thx for your reply. I'm not sure how to set option 1, System.setProperty("user.timezone", "EST");. Is this in java application itself ? As for setting parameter.. I open the java control panel, advanced and then under Java runtime parameters and entered the setting -Duser.timezone="EST". Relaunched application, still no luck. I did notice the change was applied to deployment.properties.   Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Yes, the first suggestion was to add the code line in the program itself. The other option is used as a parameter to the program. Since it's a web start program I guess it can be a bit tricky to use the second option. Have you written the program yourself or are you just running a program that you don't have control over?

Comment: The application is web based.. I guess I will then need to ask the app developer to make the change, correct?  or Can I add the line of code to a batch file of some sort before launching application ?

Comment: You could try this:
Download the file *.jnlp that starts the application and save it locally. Then open a command prompt and start the application with `javaws -J-Duser.timezone="EST" yourapp.jnlp`

Comment: The applicaiton save as target is greyed out from IE broswer, not sure how I can downlaod it. Going to contact the applicaiton team, to see if the can do a code change System.setProperty("user.timezone", "EST");.... thx